# UnauthorizedAccessException while reading SQL Server MDF file which was just create by mstest

Tags: sql-server

In mstest unittest I am connected to MSSQL server then do following steps:

```
CREATE DATABASE testDB ON PRIMARY (NAME = testDB, FILENAME = 'c:\...\original.mdf', SIZE = 5MB) LOG ON (NAME = testDB_log, FILENAME = 'C:\...\original.ldf', SIZE = 1MB)
```

Then applying some scripts using sqlcmd

```
sqlcmd -S "MyPC" -i "C:\...\createTable.sql" -f 65001 -d testDB -b
```

And then detach the database

```
USE master IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysdatabases WHERE name ='testDB') ALTER DATABASE [testDB] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

USE master IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysdatabases WHERE name ='testDB') exec sp_detach_db 'testDB'
```

Finally from unittest by C# I want to read MDF file which was created in the first step but I have no right to so it (UnauthorizedAccessException).

I use following connection string:

```
Server=MyPC;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

How it is possible that I can create database but I cannot read resulted MDF file after detaching the database. I use